# Linux kernel module file size

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, kernel, kernel-modules

I'm trying to update the kernel on a CentOS 6 machine with a vanilla 3.1.0-rc10 kernel.  It seems to work, except the modules that get created are significantly larger in size than those that come from the distro RPM.  Thats an issues, because the `mkinitrd` command ends up creating a initram file that is 100M (because of the some of all the modules inside) in size.  Grub takes forever to load and decompress a 100M initram file at boot.

In short:

1. I downloaded the kernel code.
2. Copied the running kernel config from/boot/config-2.6.xxx to .config in my kernel code dir.
3. ran `make oldconfig` and accepted the defaults
4. ran `make && make modules_install`
5. ran `mkinitrd /boot/initramfs-3.1.0-rc10.x86_64.img 3.1.0-rc10`

The resulting /boot/initramfs-3.1.0-rc10.x86_64.img is 100M in size.

Its clearly because the size of the modules is so much larger; picking the `qla4xxxx` you can see my compiled version is 3.6M vs the distros 116K.  This is the case for all the modules.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -lh /lib/modules/2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi/qla4xxx/qla4xxx.ko
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root 116K May 19 23:37 /lib/modules/2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi/qla4xxx/qla4xxx.ko
[root@localhost ~]# ls -lh /lib/modules/3.1.0-rc10+/kernel/drivers/scsi/qla4xxx/qla4xxx.ko
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.6M Oct 21 12:57 /lib/modules/3.1.0-rc10+/kernel/drivers/scsi/qla4xxx/qla4xxx.ko
```

I've done this before without issue; what am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `strip --strip-unneeded` on the module to remove extraneous symbols. If that doesn't do it, run `size` on both modules to see where the difference lies. Note that this makes debugging somewhat more difficult.

Comment: I did try running `strip` on all the modules; but that naturally confused the hell out of `depmod`.  I was unaware of `--strip-unneeded`. thanks!